# how to request/response works in multiplayer game

Tags: network-programming, game-physics

I newbie to forum and game programming but I have a question( probably dummy question...)

I am working on a multiplayer game like a Checkers.
My architecture goes like this:

After both client sign in to game, and ready to go,
each client, in his turn makes a 'move', and send it to server to authorize it.
After server authorize movement, it then send 2 message:
1) first one for the player which make the 'move', telling him its move is granted and it now should 'wait' for the other opponent to play.
2) second message, goes to opponent, telling him what soldier move, and that now it his 'turn' to play.... bla bla bla

my silly question is: When a each client sign-in to game, a new socket created for him for communicating with server
How can I use the socket for BOTH, sending messages to server(like movement), and also for listening to responses from server(like 'your turn', 'wait'...)
is it possible or I should create another socket for 'listening' ?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I feagure it how to solve the issue.
I little changed my architecture but it goes like this.
(Since its not realtime game, i decided to use TCP instead of UDP protocol, but its another discussion...)

When the server accpect 2 players, it create GameGanager(Runnable) object and pass both sockets to it.
(Then Server and goes back for listening to next game requests...)
When client applicaion succeed to connect to server it goes to 'WAIT' state.

For each socket, GamePlayer create Player instance and pass to it the relevant socket.
Player object, among other, have 2 methods: sendMessage(), waitMessage() for communicating with client application.

GameServer sends 2 messages:
 - to 'player' initiating the game: a 'TURN' state.
 - to 'opponent': a 'WAIT' state.

When 'player' made his moves, it then sendMessage() to GameServer to authenticate the move, and goes to 'WAIT' state by calling waitMessage().
GameServer 'ACK' to player, and sends message 'TURN' to opponent.

and goes on until the game finished

Hope it will help to someone.